# React Router nesting reloads page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to set up nested routes in React using React Router so that the nested components load directly, however the page reloads when I attempt to go to a nested route.

<s>Even the official example does the same - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting</s> The official example works as expected when it is opened in a new window.

One thing I noticed was that if I actually change the route from within one of the child route components the page *does not reload*. But this is bad practice and I want to change the route in the component that defines the routes.

Has something changed recently? How can I achieve nested routes changes without page reload?

**Parent**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// At route /home
const Parent = (props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => {
  const changeRoute = () => {
    props.history.push('/home/test'); // Reloads page
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route component={Test} path="/home/test" />
        <Route component={Default} />
      </Switch>
      <button onClick={changeRoute}>Click</button>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Parent);
```

**Child**

```
const Default = (props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => {
  const changeRoute = () => {
    props.history.push('/home/test'); // Does not reload page
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={changeRoute}>Click</button>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Default);
```

I'm using react-router-dom v5.1.2.

Comment: Have you tried defining the route as a relative? `<Route component={Test} path="test" />`. Im not sure it will work but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: @SagiRika Nice suggestion but no luck.

Comment: How about switching `component` to `render`? `<Route render={Test} path="/home/test" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
 import {HashRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
```

change BrowserRouter to HashRouter and check ,it stops reload issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using `<Router>` in Parent even though Parent was itself within `<Router>` tags. Replacing `<Router>` with `<div>` in Parent fixed the issue.